# JQuery replace image with Base64 (html2canvas no proxy)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

I have a concept of what I’d like to do, but need help putting the pieces together.

I am playing around with [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html) for a feedback form. Its works well for me but my Flickr (cross domain) photograph images don’t work.

I am wondering instead of creating an entire proxy server cant I just convert the images to base64 on the client side? Then once converted just do a replace of the “data-image” src with the base64 string?

**Html**

```
<div class='container1'>
<div class='box photo col3'> <a data-image='http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3737/1530282_3bc6b9.jpg' data-toggle='lightbox' href='http://www.flickr.com/photos/1773075@N04' target='_blank'></a></div>
…..
</div>
```

**JS** (source:[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript))

```
function convertImgToBase64(url, callback, outputFormat){
    var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        img = new Image;
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function(){
        var dataURL;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        canvas.width = img.width;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
        callback.call(this, dataURL);
        canvas = null; 
    };
    img.src = url;
}
```

**Putting it together:**
Here is where I have the issues. What I am trying to do is a for each data-image in div class container1, replace the src image with a base64 string so its included in my canvas.

```
$( "data-image" ).each( function( index, element ){
    convertImgToBase64($( this ).text(), function(base64Img){
            replace $(this).attr(‘data-image’) with base64 string
    });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selector [atribute_name] get all elements with specified attribute.

Also text() get text between open and close tag, use data('image') instead.

```
$("[data-image]").each( function( index, element ){
    convertImgToBase64($( this ).data('image'), function(base64Img){
        $(element).attr('src', base64Img);
    });

});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3m0sqveu/)

Comment: The jquery.attr doesnt seem to take so Im trying with a static image and still not seeing it replace the images:  $("[data-image]").each( function( index, element ){$(this).attr('data-image', 'images/splash.png');});

Comment: Ahh, my fault, it should be attr('src', ...).

Comment: @Chris I've added a demo